# Bootstrap 'fade in' on modal makes modal content iframe and jsp invisible on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am having some issues with `bootstrap 3.1.1` and the modal. I have been transferring some legacy web code to this for our page: new modal.

Problem is, when i add the content- which consists of an iframe with a 3rd party jsp-applet inside of it:

The JSP is never shown on Firefox!

If i manually remove the `fade` and `in` class of the modal using Firebug the JSP appears. I have looked into it and in our code we added `fade in` to the classes of the modal. Removing this removed the `fade` class, but it seems the `in` class is added by the bootstrap modal.js around line         `71: .addClass('in')`.

This surely sounds like a bug in bootstrap, my questions are:

Can I easily bypass this animation without changing the bootstrap specific code?

Has anybody else experienced similar issues?

Comment: Have you tried updating to v3.2.0?

Comment: Yes updating does not work. Resorted to adding jquery to manually remove class "in".